# Searching between two comma separated fields

Tags: sql, mysql

Assume these two tables:

**blog**

```
id title      keywords
1  Hello      hello,world,test
2  Google     search, email, security
3  Microsoft  clippy, collaboration
```

**category**

```
id keywords
1  test, world, clippy
```

How do I search for blog rows that have one or more keyword matching a keyword in the category row?

Comment: Any chance you can change this datamodel?  There would be better ways of storing this to allow for more efficient searching.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'm not sure, but I think the susbtring function will probably be very useful to you. More string functions here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html
A long-term solution would be refactoring keywords to a separate table and then using a blogs_keywords table to store pairs of blog id and keyword id.

Comment: I know, but I can't change it. A lot of mess will need to be cleaned up that I can't currently commit to.

Comment: start with look on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set -  SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');

Comment: @Haim: I am familiar with FIND_IN_SET, but you can't use it with LIKE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Succinctly: if you want to do that operation, you don't store your data like that.  You normalize your data, and search using the normalized data:

```
CREATE TABLE Blog
(
    id      INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Blog(id, title) VALUES(1, 'Hello');
INSERT INTO Blog(id, title) VALUES(2, 'Google');
INSERT INTO Blog(id, title) VALUES(3, 'Microsoft');

CREATE TABLE BlogKeywords
(
    id      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    keyword VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(keyword, id)
);

INSERT INTO BlogKeywords(id, keyword) VALUES(1, 'hello');
INSERT INTO BlogKeywords(id, keyword) VALUES(1, 'world');
INSERT INTO BlogKeywords(id, keyword) VALUES(1, 'test');
INSERT INTO BlogKeywords(id, keyword) VALUES(2, 'search');
INSERT INTO BlogKeywords(id, keyword) VALUES(2, 'email');
INSERT INTO BlogKeywords(id, keyword) VALUES(2, 'security');
INSERT INTO BlogKeywords(id, keyword) VALUES(3, 'clippy');
INSERT INTO BlogKeywords(id, keyword) VALUES(3, 'collaboration');

CREATE TABLE Category
(
    id      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    keyword VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id, keyword)
);

INSERT INTO Category(id, keyword) VALUES(1, 'test');
INSERT INTO Category(id, keyword) VALUES(1, 'world');
INSERT INTO Category(id, keyword) VALUES(1, 'clippy');
```

Now you can search easily using simple joins:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.id AS BlogID, b.Title, c.id AS CategoryID
  FROM Blog AS b
  JOIN BlogKeywords AS K ON b.id      = k.id
  JOIN Category     AS C ON k.keyword = c.keyword;
```

It isn't completely clear what you'd want to see if there were multiple catagories.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a good way using a simple query. If you really must have this sort of data model, the only way I see is by traversing the table and matching each row yourself. You could do this in a stored procedure or from client code. Yes, it will be horrible, but the query engine can't do any better anyway. Be sure to use a cursor and not load the entire table in your app memory.